# Why is tex designed to render spaces around brackets?

Tags: spacing, tex-core

When I wrote following lines:

```
\section{Introduction}{
  Content in introduction ...
}
```

Unwanted space comes before `Content` as warned.

I understand it's due to some technical decision in tex. But I wonder the reasons behind this decision.

At the beginning of text tags in HTML, literal spaces do not get rendered. I actually prefer behavior like this, because it makes my handcrafted code more readable.

By the way, can I have tex ignore spaces between `{` and `Content` of this code?

Comment: You don't need to put the contents of the introduction between braces to begin with.

Comment: @egreg But some brackets can't be omitted, like in `\institute{}`.

Comment: Use a comment character: `{%` then start a newline.  If you skip the 'philosophical' reasons, it is just a matter of getting used to how TeX works --- and knowing when and where and why braces are needed.  (Why in this case relates to the number of arguments a command like `\section` needs, not 'why' whitespace is important in macros.)  I would also imagine any workaround would be a lot more trouble than it's worth to implement, and probably quite fragile to boot.

Comment: @jon Thanks, the `{%` works. But I don't understand the behavior here. Does that mean `%` in first line comments out spaces in second line?

Comment: If it helps to think of it that way: the comment character, `%`, tells TeX to treat the rest of the line as a comment, and spaces are skipped at the start of an input line.  (Line ends, however, is one place where spurious spaces can creep in.)

Comment: If you want more detail, see chapter two of *TeX by Topic*; try `texdoc texbytopic` if on TeX Live.

Comment: Are you sure your claim is correct?! I don't see any extra space at all when I expand your code into an MWE and compile it.

Answer (score 20):

Commands that *expect* an argument can be defined to ignore white space (typically use of `\ignorespaces` and/or `\unskip`)  (eg `\footnotetext{     a}` is the same as `\footnotetext{a}`   the fact that spaces are not ignored around `{}` in running text is a general feature so `\LaTeX{} is...` is a common way of making the space appear.

HTML is different as it is a *fixed* tag set and special parsing rules are added for each element. XML does not drop white space for example. So the situation in TeX is similar to that in XHTML: The parser does not drop space but the definition of particular commands may be such that it ignores the space tokens.

Comment: Have you checked whether the OP's claim is even correct? I, for one, can't reproduce his claim about an extra, unwanted space showing up if I expand his code snippet into an MWE.

Comment: @Mico good catch:-)

Answer (score 15):

Ignoring the spaces after `\section{Introduction}` is standard LaTeX behavior, with or without braces. Spaces do not appear in the output before "Content" in the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}{
  Content in introduction ...
}
\end{document}
```

This uses the article document class, but most of the common classes behave the same.

So the problem occurs because of something else in your document. I suspect an odd definition of `\section`, either in your document or in your document class.

Comment: Welcome Dan, er, @user37136 (you *can* change this if you like.) :)

Answer (score 10):

The `\section` command has *one* mandatory argument, the section title (and an optional argument, but this is irrelevant here).

The text of the section goes after the title and *not* inside braces:

```
 \section{Introduction}

 This is silly text, but shows how one should do.

 The introduction has more than one paragraph; paragraphs
 are separated by a blank line.

 Enough for the introduction.

 \section{Main results}

 Here we'll show the wonderful results we got.

 ...
```

LaTeX is not HTML and has no concept of tags similar to HTML ones, though some constructs (the environments) can remind of them.